# RAID 5 reshape freeze

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I recently added a new disk to my RAID5 array and started growing it. Absent minded as I am I rebooted the server during this reshape process I as another program was hung and blocking some ports. Thinking of it now it might have been because the array hung but I cannot be sure.

I started the grow process with the following command:

```
$ mdadm --grow --raid-devices=4 /dev/md0
```

After this reboot the reshape process has frozen at `28%`. I can no longer mount the array, stop it or anything it just seem to have frozen up.

Here is some info on the array:

```
# mdadm -D /dev/md0

/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Sat Mar 28 17:31:15 2015
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 5860063744 (5588.59 GiB 6000.71 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2930031872 (2794.30 GiB 3000.35 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Sun Jun  7 11:04:28 2015
          State : clean, reshaping 
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 256K

 Reshape Status : 28% complete
  Delta Devices : 1, (3->4)

           Name : ocular:0  (local to host ocular)
           UUID : e1f7a83b:2e43c552:84d09d04:b1416cb2
         Events : 344582

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       4       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       1       8       49        1      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       3       8       65        2      active sync   /dev/sde1
       5       8       33        3      active sync   /dev/sdc1
```

and

```
# cat /proc/mdstat 

Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : active raid5 sdb1[4] sdc1[5] sde1[3] sdd1[1]
      5860063744 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 256k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      [=====>...............]  reshape = 28.6% (840259584/2930031872) finish=524064.9min speed=66K/sec
      bitmap: 3/22 pages [12KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

Trying to mount the array just hangs

```
# mount /dev/md0 /mnt/storage/
```

And the same if I try to stop the array

```
# mdadm -S /dev/md0
```

I have also tried growing it down to 3 devices again but it is busy with the last reshape:

```
# mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --raid-devices=3

mdadm: /dev/md0 is performing resync/recovery and cannot be reshaped
```

I tried to mark the new drive as faulty to see if the reshape would stop but to no avail. It works to mark it as failed but nothing happens.

I also tried to run a check instead of a reshape (as I read somewhere this fixed a similar problem) but the device is busy

```
# echo check>/sys/block/md0/md/sync_action

-bash: echo: write error: Device or resource busy
```

What does this mean? I'm on really thin ice here with no idea what to do so any help is greatly appreciated.

### EDIT

Pretty sure the reboot was not the cause of the problem. It seems to be some problem with the reshape that causes the array to hang. I get these errors in dmesg:

```
[  360.625322] INFO: task md0_reshape:126 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  360.625351]       Not tainted 4.0.4-2-ARCH #1
[  360.625367] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  360.625394] md0_reshape     D ffff88040af57a58     0   126      2 0x00000000
[  360.625397]  ffff88040af57a58 ffff88040cf58000 ffff8800da535b20 00000001642a9888
[  360.625399]  ffff88040af57fd8 ffff8800da429000 ffff8800da429008 ffff8800da429208
[  360.625401]  0000000096400e00 ffff88040af57a78 ffffffff81576707 ffff8800da429000
[  360.625403] Call Trace:
[  360.625410]  [<ffffffff81576707>] schedule+0x37/0x90
[  360.625428]  [<ffffffffa0120de9>] get_active_stripe+0x5c9/0x760 [raid456]
[  360.625432]  [<ffffffff810b6c70>] ? wake_atomic_t_function+0x60/0x60
[  360.625436]  [<ffffffffa01246e0>] reshape_request+0x5b0/0x980 [raid456]
[  360.625439]  [<ffffffff81579053>] ? schedule_timeout+0x123/0x250
[  360.625443]  [<ffffffffa011743f>] sync_request+0x28f/0x400 [raid456]
[  360.625449]  [<ffffffffa00da486>] ? is_mddev_idle+0x136/0x170 [md_mod]
[  360.625454]  [<ffffffffa00de4ba>] md_do_sync+0x8ba/0xe70 [md_mod]
[  360.625457]  [<ffffffff81576002>] ? __schedule+0x362/0xa30
[  360.625462]  [<ffffffffa00d9e54>] md_thread+0x144/0x150 [md_mod]
[  360.625464]  [<ffffffff810b6c70>] ? wake_atomic_t_function+0x60/0x60
[  360.625468]  [<ffffffffa00d9d10>] ? md_start_sync+0xf0/0xf0 [md_mod]
[  360.625471]  [<ffffffff81093418>] kthread+0xd8/0xf0
[  360.625473]  [<ffffffff81093340>] ? kthread_worker_fn+0x170/0x170
[  360.625476]  [<ffffffff8157a398>] ret_from_fork+0x58/0x90
[  360.625478]  [<ffffffff81093340>] ? kthread_worker_fn+0x170/0x170
```

Also, looking at CPU usage md0_raid5 seems to be having problems:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ S COMMAND
 125 root      20   0    0.0m   0.0m 100.0  0.0  35:57.44 R  `- md0_raid5
 126 root      20   0    0.0m   0.0m   0.0  0.0   0:00.06 D  `- md0_reshape
```

Could this be why the reshape has stopped?

Is it possible to revert to using 3 drives again without losing data?

Answer (score 1):

From man mdadm(8):

> Changing the number of active devices in a RAID5 or RAID6 is much more
>   effort. Every block in the array will need to be read and written back
>   to a new location. From 2.6.17, the Linux Kernel is able to increase
>   the number of devices in a RAID5 safely, including restarting an
>   interrupted "reshape". From 2.6.31, the Linux Kernel is able to
>   increase or decrease the number of devices in a RAID5 or RAID6.

So mdadm is perfectly capable of resume an interrupted grown. However, you **must** use a backup file (with --backup-file) in order to have resume (or abort) capability.

See also [here](http://www.spinics.net/lists/raid/msg40771.html) for more information.

What was the **exact** command you run? Anyway, I suggest you to post your problem on the *[linux-raid](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#linux-raid)* mailing list.

Comment: Ok. I didnt use a backup file but it resumed from the same position after reboot.

Comment: I added the grow command to the question. Thanks for the mailing list suggestion. Ill try my luck there as well.